# how to send list of records belongs to three tables from controller to view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have three tables like

Categories  ---->Id,Name

CategoryCertifications --->CategoryId,CertificationId

Certifications ----->Id,Name,Summary

I want to display list of  certificationName and summary in view page.

I tried Like this

`ViewBag.CategoryCertifications=from pd in db.categories join od in db.categorycertifications on pd.id equals od.CategoryId join ct in db.certifications on od.certificationId equals ct.id select new 
{
ct.Name,ct.Summary
}).ToList();`

In ViewPage I mentioned Like Below

```
var categories=(List<Certification>ViewBag.CategoryCertifications ?? new List<Certification>();
```

I got the following error in viewpage

```
unable to cast object of type'system.collection.generic.list''[<>f_Anonymous type 2f'2[system.string,system.string]]' to type 'system.collection.generic.list' '[cn.models.Certification]'
```

Thanks for advance..

Comment: DO you have models for each of the tables already?

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the data type of the variables?

Suggestion: Try creating a custom model in the models folder of the required type and create an instance of it. Then append data to the model and simply pass the custom object to the view ...

Answer (score 0):

Since your class certifications contains `Id ,Name, Summary`

and the following query would return type that contains `name and summary`

```
 ViewBag.CategoryCertifications=from pd in db.categories join od in db.categorycertifications on pd.id equals od.CategoryId join ct in db.certifications on od.certificationId equals ct.id select new { ct.Name,ct.Summary }).ToList();
```

so both are incompatible, so casting not possible here, instead you can do like,

instead of casting i.e. this line

```
var categories=(List<Certification>ViewBag.CategoryCertifications ?? new List<Certification>();
```

just write directly use the `ViewBag.CategoryCertifications` in the view. so at runtime properties will bind. make sure of the properties names the you use in the view. They should be `ct.Name,ct.Summary` hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewBag.CategoryCertifications=from pd in db.categories join od in
db.categorycertifications on pd.id equals od.CategoryId join ct in db.certifications on
od.certificationId equals ct.id select new 
{
ct.Name,ct.Summary
}).ToList();
```

In the above code you are returning anonymous list to the view and trying to cast it to list of Certification, hence the error comes.

try this:

```
ViewBag.CategoryCertifications=from pd in db.categories join od in
db.categorycertifications on pd.id equals od.CategoryId join ct in db.certifications on
od.certificationId equals ct.id select new Certification
{
Name=ct.Name,Summary=ct.Summary
}).ToList();
```

In this case list of certification will be passed to view.